# Supporting color blind users

Tags: android, accessibility, color-blindness

I have an app that consists of falling shapes of different colors on a completely black background.

Because the game heavily relies on color, I want it to be accessible to color blind users.

How can I achieve this?

Ideally, I would like a method that just takes any color, and converts it to the color a color blind person would need to see to perceive the original color. For example.

```
private float[] convertToColorBlindColor(float R, float G, float B) {
    // logic
    return new float[] {R, G, B};
}
```

Comment: Its not that simple, because color blindness isn't really a binary thing.  There's a variety of different types (http://www.colourblindawareness.org/colour-blindness/types-of-colour-blindness/).  There's a lot of research out there on how to pick good colors for color blind users, I think you're going to need to do some reading on it.

Comment: Just an **idea** (how I would do the **trick**): put a NUMBER or LETTER inside each color block - If it's a Tetris-clone, imagine each red square containig "A", each Green square containing "B", and so on. So color blinds will at least recognize the letters as part of a group.

Comment: An advice from geographical maps: you can add dashes (vertical, horizontal, 45°, 135°), dots, checker, etc to make a visual difference other than color. Shapes also (test http://wave.webaim.org on any webpage and see how results are displayed in green, yellow, red AND different shapes. [Example](http://opensolution.org/os/templates/img/guides/webaim-validator.png) ). Game of Mahjong (sp?) too or other symbols

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I think I'm gonna go with the letters inside the shapes

Comment: You can also test your game in grayscale, which simulates the most restrictive form of color blindness (monochromacy) and encompasses all other forms as well.

Comment: As a side note, what you should be concerned about is the perceptual brightness of the colors that you're using. It's fine to use red and green at the same time as long as they have different perceptual brightness levels.

Comment: Can you not allow the color deficient user choose their own colors?  They have the only chance of picking colors that have sufficient contrast for their specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest including a setting in the app which a color blind person should enable if they are color blind. When enabled your app should then snap colors to a color blind safe pallet e.g. see the 15 color pallet example here: http://www.somersault1824.com/tips-for-designing-scientific-figures-for-color-blind-readers/

You can then test what your app would like for specific type of color blindness using the Android Developer options settings on your emulator/device called "Simulate colour space" which has the options:
1. Monochromacy
2. Deuteranomaly 
3. Protanomaly
4. Tritanomaly